# Which virtual machine allows forwarding host partition to guest

Tags: virtual-machine

I have dual system on my laptop, one Windows 7 and one Fedora 18, and I want to access linux partition under windows. As there are no BtrFS driver support in windows, somebody suggests me to work like this:

1. install an virtual machine on windows
2. install an lightweight linux on virtual machine
3. **some virtualization software allows forwarding host partition to guest**. Forward the host linux partition to guest linux and mount it.
4. expose that partition by SAMBA server in the guest linux.
5. mount it on host as a network partition

It seems the free VirtualBox cannot do that. I wonder if there are any virtulization software can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it right, you're trying to access your LINUX partitions as data drives from Windows 7, and if that is your goal, the ExtFS project provides a Windows driver to accomplish exactly that.

It is free, widely used and I've personally relied on it for its reliability.

http://www.ext2fsd.com/